# Sending the enter key located on the lower right of the numeric keypad in Dragon NaturallySpeaking

Tags: keyboard, dragon-naturally-speaking

A typical qwerty keyboard has two <kbd>ENTER</kbd>  keys:

[image]

With Dragon NaturallySpeaking 12.5, if I say "press enter", it will send the green enter key. How to send the red enter key? (i.e., the enter key located on the lower right of the numeric keypad)

I use Dragon NaturallySpeaking 12.5 Professional on Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

---

I unsuccessfully tried:

- `press return`
- `press numeric enter`

Comment: What problem are you trying to prevent by sending the enter key on the numpad?

Comment: @Ramhound some programs distinguish those two keys.

Comment: I deal with IBM mainframes daily, so I am aware of the difference between the two keys, but understanding what you are trying to prevent helps me understand your problem.  Understanding the problem allows me to answer your question.  I will never unstand the reason people avoid answering some of the questions I asked.

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks for the answer! I sometimes don't mention the purpose in order to narrow down the discussion ( e.g., if I say my motivation is to use keypad enter in program X, I could get some answer that the keyboard shortcut can be change to something else).

Comment: It is safe to assume, if I ask a question, I have a specific reason I am asking it.  By answering that question, you increase the chances, I am able to answer the question itself.  I don't often go into the reasons I want to know something, I would spend more time explaining the reasons, for a single question to a single person, and likely still not recieve the answer to the question I asked even after I did that.

Comment: @Ramhound Sorry, I thought you meant systematically mentioning the purpose in the question itself. Definitely, in the comments, one should state the purpose if asked, as long as there is not confidentiality issues, which shouldn't happen frequently.

Comment: You are just the most recent person, who seemed to avoid answering a question, when i had a specific reason for the asking it.  So my response is nothing personally.  Simply saying that the software, you are trying to use, has two seperate features map to those keys would have been fine.  What software it is not important, I might want to know personally at that point, but only for curosity sakes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close.

### Pressing function and numeric keypad keys

> To press a function key (F1 to F12), say "Press Function" and then the
>   name of the key. For example, say "Press Function 1" to bring up the
>   online Help. To press the keys on the numeric keypad, say "Press
>   Keypad" and then the name of the key. For example, you can say "Press
>   Keypad Minus" to press the keyboard shortcut that opens the Correction
>   menu. See the complete list below:

i am only going to list the one you are interested in, which means, you would have to say:

**Keypad Enter**

**Note:**

> Num Lock must be on for the "**Press Keypad**" commands to work. You can
>   say "**Press Num Lock**" to turn Num Lock on.

[Pressing Keyboard Keys](http://www.nuance.com/naturallyspeaking/customer-portal/documentation/userguide/chapter4/ug_chapter4_pressing_keyboard_keys.asp)